# Set LinearLayout to 16:9 in Android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, aspect-ratio

Is there a way to set a LinearLayout to 16:9 and center to screen using Android Studio?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and when needed, how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can try to help you with a problem. You're often expected to do your own homework and research before asking a question.

Comment: Please provide some more detail what you want to achieve, use Pictures by demontrating what you want if you can.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use a ConstraintLayout, then you can center it and use

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio
```